# How do I clear 2 items from my inventory, with one being a specific name?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I am working on my ***VANILLA*** Minecraft server right now and I'm in a bit of a struggle. A player can purchase an iron sword called SLAYER Sword, and can also purchase a regular iron sword. A player can also sell an iron sword at a price of 3 Scoreboard Units. I want ONLY the regular iron sword to be sold, not the SLAYER Sword. The text I am currently using to sell a single sword is `/clear @p minecraft:iron_sword -1 1`. This is currently clearing BOTH swords, not just the regular iron sword.

Comment: Please do not edit the title to "[SOLVED]", if you have found the answer then post one

Comment: Yep, don't do that. Only do that in forums. In StackExchange sites, use the tick if the answer works

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out: make the regular iron sword-giver have a custom name of Iron Sword, which can be done by adding `{display:{Name:"Iron Sword"}}`. In the seller, make it clear the sword by adding the same display name.